How to simulate a client Authenticator for a 2FA to login into a remote app as a user?
I have a nodejs JS that simulates a user accessing to a application webpage. This application implemented a 2FA and i need to update the script to handle the 2FA.
How to make a sort of Google Authenticator to run in the script, to simulate the user making the authentication 2FA?
When I search for this, I only found how to implement the server side for 2FA.
I am not sure if the speakeasy can be used to generate TOTP tokens to reply to the 2FA, but if so, how to register (reading the QR Code)?

TOTP libraries take a secret (and look at the clock) and produce a 6 digit code. You can use these libraries for this usecase. On the server-side you after all need to check if someone's submitted code is correct. To find out what the correct code is, you need to produce the number.
